# Envio de requisição GET

Tags: libcurl, requisição, amazon-aws

Estou tentando enviar uma requisição do tipo GET para outro computador (Win Server R2 2008), a partir de uma instância EC2 AWS (Linux) através do cURL pelo comando `$curl -X GET --header "Authorization: bearer <token>" http://<ip destino>:8080/<endpoint>` e me retorna `RFB 003.008
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`. mas não tenho ideia do que seja esse erro.

Comment: Use `--trace-ascii dump.txt` junto com comando para poder debugar o erro com mais detalhes

Comment: @caribeedu já fiz só me retorna o mesmo erro só que com o header mais detalhado :/

Comment: Olha esta pergunta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285700/curl-error-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer-php-curl)

Comment: @IkaroSales Sua instância EC2 precisa ter conectividade com a internet e eventualmente com sua rede interna através de uma VPN ou Dirrect Connect. Sugiro que faça alguns testes simples como pingar de/para e editar sua pergunta com estes detalhes. O tópico acesso a rede na documentação da AWS pode te ajudar: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html